# Dynamic filtering a datagridview in wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagridview, filtering

I am trying to filter a datagridview dynamically, which is filled by input of an xml, using a textbox.

If I start the debugging mode, 
- the form will be loaded
- the datagridview will be filled by the input of an xml file (Form1_FormLoad)
- I can add some input to the datagrid view 
- I can update a selected row 
- I can choose the path where the datagridview should be saved as xml
- I could save the edited/unedited datagridview to an xml file

The saving happens on a equal way like the xml-reading/opening.

---

But what ever I try, I can't filter this data unbinded datagridview.

I've found 2 methods. Both have the disadvantage (for me as noob) that I have to bind the data first. So, If I would use them I would have to rewrite the whole other code of saving, loading, adding and updating. Because I couldnt add a new row to a data binded source.(error message)

So I would be happy, if someone can suggest some ideas/solutions how I can realize the filtering without 
- public dataset `ds` get; set;
- adding the input of a datagrid in the code

The Code describes the method how I add the xml-input to the datagrid view.
I search solutions since 1 week. Had one, but there the datagrid view would become empty If I write a single letter in the textbox.. And If I erase the single letter, the datagridview would still be empty.

PS. I would like to say, that I dont have any clue of coding. I've searched several coding-snippets and tried them^^ :/
If someone asks, I can post the 2 methods how it works. I tried them too :)

```
pathbox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.pathbox;

string somePath = pathbox.Text;
string filename = "test.xml";
string path = Path.Combine(somePath, filename);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(path);

foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["Player"].Rows)
{

    int n = dgw1.Rows.Add();
    dgw1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["Name"].ToString();
    dgw1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Age"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You sound reluctant to use data binding, but that is the correct path to go for an editable `DataGridView`.  That said, you would not want to just add new rows to the DGV, but instead should add new objects to the `DataSource` - the DGV will update itself accordingly. ---On another note: you're either using a `DataGridView` or `WPF`, the two are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

"Because I couldnt add a new row to a data binded source.(error message)"
Why not?

If you databind it to items in an ObservableCollection, adding snd removing items from the collection would automatically update the view side of it (the datagrid).

I would strongly recommend to use binding, which is a very strong argument for using WPF in the first place.

Look at mvvm pattern. You can probably reuse most of your code. But just moving it to a Viewmodel. Then you get good code separation as well.

Comment: The issue is I dont have any clue of programming or coding.^^ I know that I add Entries by String to the dgv. I can delete them.. update them.. and i can save the edited dgv in a xml-file.. and after that the edited new old xml will be opened if i will open the program again and its content will be displayed in the datagridview... and then i can add new data. etc etc... all what I need (the last what i want to implement) is a simple code for searching/filtering the dgv by using text in a textbox dynamically... only a code. I would pay for it.

Comment: ok... I want to apologize for my ignorance :/ and my tunnelview XD... now, i can filter by using the datatable xml as datasource for my new datatable..i bindet it as source to my dgv. and then i can filter it.. thank you. so all what i have to change now. is the code for the adding, the deleting, the updating and saving . thank you for showing me a solution , a way. a hope XD

Comment: but now. i have a question. how can i add delete, update. and save a datagrid, which i filtered using datatable. binding source and co?